# Trying to run a spark job in linux to parse a large amount of tab deliminted data and index on column six. Getting permission denied

Tags: c#

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
    StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(@"/data/1/projects/data1.txt");
    char[] delimiter = new char[] { '\t' };
    string[] columnheaders = streamreader.ReadLine().Split(delimiter);
    foreach (string columnheader in columnheaders)
    {
        datatable.Columns.Add(columnheader); // I've added the column headers here.
    }

    while (streamreader.Peek() > 0)
    {
        DataRow datarow = datatable.NewRow();
        datarow.ItemArray = streamreader.ReadLine().Split(delimiter);
        datatable.Rows.Add(datarow);
    }

    foreach (DataRow row in datatable.Rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(""----Row No: " + datatable.Rows.IndexOf(row) + "----"");

        foreach (DataColumn column in datatable.Columns)
        {
            //check what columns you need
            if (column.ColumnName == "Column6") 
            {
                Console.Write(column.ColumnName);
                Console.Write(" ");
                Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
            }
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Getting permission denied at /data/1/projects/data1.txt
Also would this index into parquet files the rows based on column six. Sorry new to Linux and aws

Expecting an output file indexed by column six
changed file locations and directories for data1.txt
Spent most of time on the EMR cluster

I am using VSCODE terminal to execute on my desktop first before loading to EMR cluster

Comment: How is it related to python tag? The code you show is certainly not python (C#?)

Answer (score 1):

Try running VS as administrator or ensure you have the right permission on the file:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx ##folder path##
```

Comment: Under no circumstances is world writable the "right permission." This is dangerous and unnecessary.